# Explicit presentation of the ring of 2 by 2 real matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

Let $e_{11}, e_{12}, e_{21}, e_{22}$ denote the standard basis of the real vector space $M_{2\times 2}({\mathbb{R}})$ of $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries. That is to say, the matrix $e_{ij}$ has a $1$ in the $(i,j)$th entry and a $0$ elsewhere.

Now viewing $M_{2\times 2}({\mathbb{R}})$ as an algebra over the real numbers, what is the kernel of the algebra epimorphism $\phi: {\mathbb{R}}[e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}] \to M_{2\times 2}({\mathbb{R}})$ which sends each $e_{ij}$ to itself?

More precisely, can a finite collection $f_1(e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}),\ldots, f_n(e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22})$ of polynomials in the variables $e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}$ be explicitly given such that $\ker \phi$ is the subalgebra of ${\mathbb{R}}[e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}]$ generated by $f_1,\ldots, f_n$?

Comment: You want noncommutative polynomials here, which are sometimes denoted $\mathbb{R} \langle e_{11}, e_{12}, e_{21}, e_{22} \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over any commutative ring $k$, you can present $M_n(k)$ as a $k$-algebra by generators $e_{ij}, 1 \le i, j \le n$ and relations

$$e_{ij} e_{jk} = e_{ik}, 1 \le i, j, k \le n$$

and all other products of the generators are zero. Equivalently, it's the [category algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_algebra) over $k$ of the category consisting of $n$ objects $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ each of which is uniquely isomorphic via a unique isomorphism $e_{ij} : i \sim j$.

In general, given a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ and a basis $e_i$ of it, you can write down a presentation just by writing down all relations $e_i e_j = \sum c_{ijk} e_k$.